# Mask formatting

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to format the "cnpj" field in my application to the default on the first line. But what happens is that it looks like this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixiOy.png)

On the second line it is correct, but without any formatting. Does anyone know how to solve this zeros issue? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVIYO.png)

I needed something like: 00.036.569/0001-07

Comment: please add your code in text format, not images